# difference b/w copy and javac destdir

Tags: ant, copy

I am going through ant build.xml file in a tutorial.I am confused b/w the copy tag and destdir attribute of javac tag.

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

As per my understanding javac destdir attribute place the generated class files in the mentioned directory. As per the above code copy is also doing the same thing then what is the purpose of using both at the same time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fileset in the `copy`:

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
```

is specifying that the copy should copy everything which is not a java file. This is presumably things like images and properties files.

So the `javac` task is compiling the Java source and putting the class files in the destination directory and the copy is adding other resources.